# bitbucket plugin in jenkins pipeline should have several repositories as trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

We use several git repositories of sources for common builds. Because not only one, but several of them might be changed alone, we would need several repositories to be checked to trigger invocation of a jenkins pipeline script.

I guess, that others might also be interested in this kind of extended functionality. Any proposal/hint how to resolve this is highly appreciated.

We have not implemented yet the bitbucket plugin use, because this would be to incomplete to serve our needs now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [web hooks](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)

Put your web hook at project level, and changes to repositories within the project will trigger the web hook.

Then on the Jenkins side you will need the [Generic Webhook Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)

Bitbucket sends a json payload to Jenkins which consumes the payload.

You can use the [Json path expression tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) to get relevant fields from the payload. From that you can decide what build should be triggered.

[image]

The newer way of doing this is to use the [Bitbucket Server plugin for Jenkins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-FugzVYJQU)

Comment: Thanks, we will try webhooks in the first place after internal discussion.